# Project refresh failed - Could not connect to server

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am getting this error in my project which was working fine last night.[image]
I have my internet working fine.
I've clean/rebuild the project multiple times.
I've done the Invalidate caches/restart process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happened due to my antivirus which updated its firewall policy over night.
Disabling the firewall made it working again.
Thank you for any help BTW.